# Windows app store download permissions

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps

I developed an app for Windows phone. Now I want to deploy it on Windows app store and wants to put restriction.I want only specific people will able to install it. How can I do that. Any suggestion will be appropriated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Well that depends on who these specific people are. You can set age restrictions and region restrictions, and that's about it.

If you mean you want to hand-pick users that can *use* your app, then provide a login screen where you manually authorize your registered users.

If you mean that only users you choose can *download* the app, then you can't use the Store; you'll need to [use sideloading](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt269549(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I found this ...... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dn771706.aspx    Hope it will help me and others.

Comment: No, that's the other way around. That's for an organisation who wants to limit which apps their Windows Phone users can install on their phones.

Answer (score 0):

You can control distribution in the [Distribution and Visibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/set-app-pricing-and-availability#distribution-and-visibility) section of your app submission on the developer dashboard.

There are three basic options (for Windows 10 - two for Windows Phone 8.x):

- **Hide this app and prevent acquisition. Customers with a promotional code can still download it on Windows 10 devices**

Give codes to the people you want to be able to use the app. This is Windows 10 only.

- **Hide this app in the Store. Customers with a direct link to the app’s listing can still download it, except on Windows 8 and Windows
  8.1**

Send links to the people you want to use the app. This will work on Windows Phone 8.1 as well as Windows 10. Anybody with a link can download it though, so it won't truly limit to just the people you want to use the app.

- **Hide this app and make it available only to the people you specify below, who can download this app on Windows Phone 8.x devices. A
  promotional code may be used to download this app on Windows 10
  devices**

This is the classic beta-mode for Windows Phone 8.x. You can specify which Microsoft Accounts have access to the app.